# Django: validate_date() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'

Tags: django, validation

I try to implement validators for Django project
I've defined a file validators.py in myapp

I add validators=[validate_test] for my ran_num field
but got an error

I have another question: is it possible to control field BEFORE form submission?

**validators.py**

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


def validate_test(self, value):
    if value == 'PPP': # just test
        raise ValidationError(
            _("Test"),
            code='Test',
            params={},
        )
```

**forms.py**

```
from .validators import validate_date

class EditForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EditForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.request = request

        self.fields["asp_ent_loc"] = forms.ChoiceField(label = _("Site concerned by the operation"), widget=forms.Select, choices=SITE_CONCERNE)
        self.fields["med_num"] = forms.CharField(label = _("Trial bacth number"), required=True,validators=[validate_test] )
        self.fields["asp_ent_dat"] = forms.DateField(
                label = _("Entry date"),
                required = True,
                initial = datetime.datetime.now(),  

            )
        self.fields["asp_ent_pro_pay"] = forms.ChoiceField(label = _("Country of treatment origin in case of entry"), widget=forms.Select, choices=PAYS)
        self.fields["asp_ent_pro_sit"] = forms.ChoiceField(label = _("Processing source site in case of entry"), widget=forms.Select, choices=SITE_PROVENANCE)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(EditForm, self).clean()

    class Meta:
        model = Entree
        fields = ('asp_ent_loc','med_num','asp_ent_dat','asp_ent_pro_pay','asp_ent_pro_sit',)

    def clean_med_num(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['med_num']
        if len(data) != 3:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("Error on Batch number format (3 letters)"))
        if not Medicament.objects.filter(med_num = data).exists():
            raise ValidationError(_('Batch number does not exist'))
        return data

    def clean_asp_ent_dat(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['asp_ent_dat']
        entrydate = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(data), "%Y-%m-%d")
        currentdate = datetime.datetime.now()
        if entrydate > currentdate:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("Please control entry date"))
        return data
```

Comment: is it `validate_test` or `validate_date`? and where is that validator? in you modelform or outside?

Comment: validate_test...

Comment: and where is that validitor? outside modelform?

Comment: root of myapp and I import files in models.;py or forms.py

Comment: remove `self` from `validate_test(self, value)` and change it to `validate_test(value)`

Answer (score 0):

Your Validation function is not a model's method which means it doesn't accept the `self`. Your Validation func only accept value argument. In your scenario-

```
def validate_test(value): # remove self from here
    if value == 'PPP':
        raise ValidationError(
            _("Test"),
            code='Test',
            params={},
        )
```

Comment: if I can't remove self then what is the other solution.

Comment: I am using    data = self.get_initial()    in validator function. I have to pass the self param. How can i call validator function now?

Comment: So, aditi you can pass self, if only the funciton is define within a class. In above code, the function didn't present in any class.

Comment: I am getting validator() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'. How can i call the validator function now?

Comment: show me the whole code snippet, then I would help you better.

Comment: Thanks for your time @yash. I wanted real time validation so instead of this I used javascript function for validation. :)